# str object doesn't support item assignment (when reading bytes)

Tags: python, iterator, binaryfiles

I have two binary data files and I want to replace the contents of part of the second binary data file 
This is the sample code I have so far

```
Binary_file1 = open("File1.yuv","rb")
Binary_file2 = open("File2.yuv","rb")

data1 = Binary_file1.read()
data2 = Binary_file2.read()

bytes = iter(data1)

for i in range(4, 10):
    data2[i] = next(bytes)
```

It fails at the part where I equate the data2[i] with next(bytes) and gives me an error saying that “'str' object does not support item assignment” 
The part I dont understand is that how is this a string object and how can I resolve this error ,Any help would be appreciated . 
PLease note the Binary files here are huge and I would like to avoid creating duplicate files as I alwyas will run into Memory Issues

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: You want to update `Binary_file2 ` but you are opening it in read mode `r`. Use `w` to open in write mode

Comment: I am using python 2

Answer (score 0):

You opened file and read it. So, You have string in `data2`. Strings do not support item assignment.

Instead, You could do:

```
data2 = data[2][:i] + next(bytes) + data[2][i + 1:]
```

Comment: Could you explain what you doing here ?

Comment: Sure. You take part of `data2` to index `i`, add `next(bytes)` and add part of `data2` from index `i+1` to the end of the `data2`. This way, item at index `i` will be replaced by `next(bytes)`.

Comment: This solution however wont work if the binary files Re huge I am dealing with 4K files here , and hence will always run in to memory issues , is there a way to resolve this , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Strings cannot be changed inplace (i.e. they are immutable).  Try this:

```
a = 'abcde'
a[2] = 'F'
```

You will get an error.  But, this will work.

```
a = a.replace(a[2], 'F')
```

You might be better off building a new string, then slicing it into your data2.

```
newstring = ''
for i in range(4, 10):
    newstring += next(bytes)

data2 = data2.replace(data2[4:10], newstring)
```

Of course, the problem here is that data2[4:10] may not be unique within data2, in which case you will have multiple replacements.  So, the following may be even better:

```
data2 = data2[:4] + newstring + data[10:]
```

Comment: the binary data files are huge so I dont want to create a new string or item for efficiency